# This release is compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement native app

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit

While uploading apk to Play store I am getting a warning saying **"This release is compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement."**. When I analyze the app architecture using Android studio. I am able to found both ".so" files under the lib folder. Here is the screenshot for that:
[image]

I have also added bellow line to my gradle file and in my used libraries too:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.user"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.3"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.rounded_green_cremeway.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
splits {
        abi {
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
```

While uploading signed Apk to play store I getting bellow issue. Please let me know if I need to do something else.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: That's not a warning, that's an Information. And it's a good one. You WANT to be compliant. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `x86` & `x86_64` are useful for the emulator, but not required there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an information, not a warning - a major and very important difference.

64Bit compliance only tells you, that **all** your native parts are available as 64Bit.

This is a good thing and not a warning. You WANT that.

You would get a warning the other way round: If there were any parts that are available *only* as 32Bit (and therefore *not* 64Bit compliant).

It's all ok with your project. Be happy if you see this information.